# Why do I get high prediction score for an image of untrained category?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, image-recognition, conv-neural-network

Im using tensorflow for image classification, for 5 categories(5 car parts). After training for 100 epochs, during prediction, when I tested an image (which does not even looks like any of  my trained category of images) it matches to one among those 5 category with the score more than 98%. (i have 1200 training images per category)
(For ex, i have trained my model with wheel,mirror,door,steering,headlamp. My testing image is Lily flower. My output is 99% with wheel) why?
Refer the parameters in my code.

```
def imagerecog(features,labels,mode,params):
input_layer = features["images"]
assert input_layer.shape[1:] == params['input_shape']
convs = []
pools = []
for i in range(params["conv_layers"]):
    if i == 0:
        convs.append(tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer,filters=params['filters'][i],
                                      kernel_size=params['kernel_size'],strides=[1,1],
                                      activation=tf.nn.relu,padding="same",name = "conv%d"%i))
    else:
        convs.append(tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pools[i-1],filters=params['filters'][i],
                                      kernel_size=params['kernel_size'],strides=[1,1],
                                      activation=tf.nn.relu,padding="same",name = "conv%d"%i))
    pools.append(tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=convs[i], pool_size=[2,2], strides=[2,2]))
flat = tf.layers.flatten(pools[-1])
dense1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=flat, units=params["hidden_units"], name="dense1", activation=tf.nn.relu)
dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense1, rate=params["drop_rate"] ,training=mode==tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN,
                            name="dropout")
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=params["n_classes"], name="logits")
probs = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits, name="probs")
top_5_scores, top_5_class = tf.nn.top_k(probs,  k=2, name="scores")

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions={"classes":top_5_class, "scores": top_5_scores})

loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
    acc = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels,predictions=top_5_class[:,0])
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops={"accuracy": acc})

opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=opt)

def inp_fn(folder,image_size):
classes = os.listdir(folder)
def fn():
    images = []
    labels = []
    for i,cls in enumerate(classes):
        imgs = os.listdir(folder+"/"+cls)
        print(cls,i)
        for img in imgs:
            img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(folder+"/"+cls+"/"+img),3,name="jpeg_decode")
            img = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(img)
            img = tf.image.resize_images(img,image_size)
            images.append(img)
            labels.append(i)
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"images":images},labels)).batch(100)
return fn


params = {"input_shape":[200,300,1],
      "conv_layers": 3,
      "filters":[20,20,20],
      "kernel_size":[5,5],
      "hidden_units": 9000,
      "drop_rate":0.4,
      "n_classes":5}

epoch=100
for a in range(epoch):
print("Epoch=",a)
estim.train(inp_fn("train",params['input_shape'][:-1]))


def pred_inp_fn(folder,image_size):
def fn():
    files = os.listdir(folder)
    images = []
    for file in files:
        img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(folder+"/"+file),3)
        img = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(img)
        img = tf.image.resize_images(img,image_size)
        images.append(img)
        return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({"images":images}).batch(100)
return fn


results = estim.predict(pred_inp_fn("predict",params['input_shape'][:-1]))


for res in results:
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, because you did not train for that category. This is an ever-present issue with neural networks (and some other ML techniques), the response of a model to unseen classes of inputs (in the case of classification) is not an even probability distribution "by default", but something unpredictable, and frequently a strong response for one of the classes (possibly the most frequent one, but not necessarily). If you think about it, all of your training examples belonged 100% to a single class, so the model will tend to give answers with the score concentrated in a single category. I wrote [another answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47013443/1782792) with a couple of alternatives to model a "non-of-the-others" class, and you can probably look up more literature on the topic. You can also look into other kinds of models, like the [object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection), if they suit better your needs. The point is that you cannot expect your model to exhibit a behavior for which it was not explicitly trained.

Answer (score 0):

You trained your model on only 5 classes. So your model is just like a baby who thinks there are only five objects in the world and tries to relate anything to one of these objects: the one it thinks is the most similar one.

One solution would be to train your model on 6 classes instead of 5, where the 6th class is the "unknown" class which includes any other object in the world (other than the five classes).

You can easily gather training data for the 6th class (it can be an image of anything but the other 5 classes) and train your model.